# Calculate Tanimoto coefficient for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, chemistry, rdkit, argument-error

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

and I want to calculate Tanimoto coefficient (Molecular similarity measure) by RDkit in python in order to have below result:
[image]

but I failed.

My data:

```
{'name': ['16β-hydro-ent-kauran-17-oic acid ',
  '16α-hydro-entkauran-17-oic acid ',
  'ent-kaur-16-en-19-oic acid',
  '16β,17-dihydroxy-ent-kauran-19-oic acid ',
  'annomontacin'],
 'canonical_smile': ['CC1(CCCC2(C1CCC34C2CCC(C3)C(C4)C(=O)O)C)C',
  'CC1(CCCC2(C1CCC34C2CCC(C3)C(C4)C(=O)O)C)C',
  'CC12CCCC(C1CCC34C2CCC(C3)C(=C)C4)(C)C(=O)O',
  'CC12CCCC(C1CCC34C2CCC(C3)C(C4)(CO)O)(C)C(=O)O',
  'CCCCCCCCCCCCC(C1CCC(O1)C(CCCCCCC(CCCCCC(CC2=CC(OC2=O)C)O)O)O)O']}
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rdkit import Chem, DataStructs
from rdkit.Chem import (
    PandasTools,
    Draw,
    Descriptors,
    MACCSkeys,
    rdFingerprintGenerator)

# Create two columns (SMILEs) from the combination of one column (SMILEs).
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df['canonical_smile'].unique(), 2)), 
                                   columns=['canonical_smile1', 'canonical_smile2']).dropna()
# Create two columns ROMoL objects from two columns (SMILEs).
    PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(df3,'canonical_smile1','ROMol1',includeFingerprints=True)
    PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(df3,'canonical_smile2','ROMol2',includeFingerprints=True)
# Calculate the circular Morgan fingerprints of two columns ROMoL objects 
df3["morgan1"] = rdFingerprintGenerator.GetFPs(df3["ROMol1"].tolist())
    df3["morgan2"] = rdFingerprintGenerator.GetFPs(df3["ROMol2"].tolist())
# Add the Tanimoto similarities between the Morgan fingerprints.
    df3["tanimoto_morgan"] = DataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(df3["morgan1"], df3["morgan2"])
```

and this is my error:

```
    ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    rdkit.DataStructs.cDataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(Series, Series)
did not match C++ signature:
    BulkTanimotoSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<unsigned __int64> v1, class boost::python::list v2, bool returnDistance=False)
    BulkTanimotoSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<unsigned int> v1, class boost::python::list v2, bool returnDistance=False)
    BulkTanimotoSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<__int64> v1, class boost::python::list v2, bool returnDistance=False)
    BulkTanimotoSimilarity(class RDKit::SparseIntVect<int> v1, class boost::python::list v2, bool returnDistance=False)
    BulkTanimotoSimilarity(class ExplicitBitVect const * __ptr64 bv1, class boost::python::api::object bvList, bool returnDistance=0)
    BulkTanimotoSimilarity(class SparseBitVect const * __ptr64 bv1, class boost::python::api::object bvList, bool returnDistance=0)
```

Comment: can you include a sample of your dataframe as formatted text so we can more easily reproduce your error? instead of the screenshots, you can copy and paste the output from `df1.head().to_dict()` into your question, thanks!

Comment: I have edited and include a sample of my dataframe @DerekO

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't have much chemistry background, but my understanding is `BulkTanimotoSimilarity` is a similarity metric between a query fingerprint and a list of target fingerprints (based on [this article](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2020/10/02/using_rdkit_bulktanimotosimilarity.html)).

From the error message, you are passing arguments that are of type `pd.Series, pd.Series` to `BulkTanimotoSimilarity` when this method expects a `SparseIntVect` and a `list` (or list-like) as inputs.

So if we take each bit vector in column `morgan1` to be your query fingerprint, and take the entire column `morgan2` to be your list of target fingerprints, we can do something like the following:

```
df3["tanimoto_morgan"] = df3['morgan1'].map(lambda morgan1: DataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(morgan1, df3['morgan2']))
```

This compiles and results in the following column being added to `df3`:

```
>>> df3['tanimoto_morgan']
0    [0.42592592592592593, 0.4107142857142857, 0.07...
1    [0.42592592592592593, 0.4107142857142857, 0.07...
2    [0.42592592592592593, 0.4107142857142857, 0.07...
3    [1.0, 0.5272727272727272, 0.0875, 0.5272727272...
4    [1.0, 0.5272727272727272, 0.0875, 0.5272727272...
5    [0.5272727272727272, 1.0, 0.08536585365853659,...
Name: tanimoto_morgan, dtype: object
```

Comment: I have got an error when I use your code. Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: @jacobdavis what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm tired, and I talked with ChatGPT, and the outcome is quite surprising. He fixed it for me, and I can now run smoothly.

`df3["tanimoto_morgan"] = [DataStructs.TanimotoSimilarity(fp1, fp2) for fp1, fp2 in zip(df3["morgan1"], df3["morgan2"])]`

Comment: that is surprising because i'm pretty certain i tried this myself and it didn't work, but it seems to work now. and my code runs too but gives you a list for each row instead of an individual value. but anyway, i'm glad you got the right answer – you might consider adding the chatgpt generated answer as an answer when you have time just to help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is as follows:

```
df3["tanimoto_morgan"] = DataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(df3["morgan1"], df3["morgan2"])
```

I have fixed it with this code below, and it now runs normally:

```
df3["tanimoto_morgan"] = [DataStructs.TanimotoSimilarity(fp1, fp2) for fp1, fp2 in zip(df3["morgan1"], df3["morgan2"])]
```